# Connecting a SuiteTalk application to a RESTlet on NetSuite

Tags: c#, netsuite

I have a SuiteTalk application developed in C# that handles order imports. I need to be able to connect the application to NetSuite so I can manually launch the imports in the event of a failure from within the user interface. I am not familiar with writing a listener application in C# so I am looking for some pointers in how I could get this to work.

-Edit- To add a limitation: I am unable to use a web server to accomplish any of this.

**How *I* think it would work:**
I am envisioning that the button push in NetSuite would make a request to the SuiteTalk application which would in turn start the task in question.

**My questions:**

- Does this logic sound right?
- Where should I start with this?
- What resources would you recommend to bring someone up to speed quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your c# application runs on your own system and uses the SOAP interface to talk to Netsuite.

There is no reasonable way to have Netsuite directly trigger your external application without your application being on the public internet listening for a request from Netsuite.  I believe you can write suitescript to access remote web services but that effectively requires a web server.

The other possibility is to create some sort of data in Netsuite that your application can poll to see if it should execute.  I'm not sure the best way to do this. Off the top of my head I think you could create a custom record type and have the button create a custom record. Your C# app could then check to see if a record of that type exists and if so execute and delete the record.

Comment: Yeah I am now realizing the limitations of no web server - I have a request in for additional resources to use for this, have to wait and see how that plays out. In the mean time I am going to write a hook around a saved search to find the internal ID of the record I need and then open the record and pull the info from netsuite rather then have it pushed to me. Just means its not as elegant a solution. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I should add that I do not recommend my first suggestion of a publicly facing server that Netsuite accesses.  This is asking for all sorts of headaches that you probably don't want to deal with.

Comment: I understand. Personally I want to have my webserver behind our firewall accepting connections on a specific port from netsuites specific IP addresses only, coupled with authentication. If you have any other ideas I am all ears.

Comment: I had a similar problem. A job that accessed Netsuite needed to be initiated by users on our local server.  I created a local web interface that they logged into and could press a button to start the process. No need to have Netsuite servers access it.

Comment: Without going into a ton more detail about my project(s) Manual restart is only a small part of this, but one that provide a solution to some of my other issues. The major requirement is to fire my application on various user events (on approval for instance) in order to get certain things to be as realtime as possible. Do you know if any other language can provide this functionality? I am not above writing a wrapper in a different language if it can solve my issue.